# Integrate C++ code with pip package?

Tags: python, c++, makefile, pip

I have a C++ project in one directory, and want that to be a part of my new pip package. I have a Makefile inside that only needs to run once during installation (`pip install <my_package>`), and then after that I don't need it anymore. How can I go about doing this cleanly?